# How can I get the count of how many times a query was matched

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Using Search I do the following.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

s = Search(using=es, index = "index_name").query('match', language = "python")

response = s.execute()

for i in response: 
    print(i)
```

Here it prints all the occurrence. I would like to see the amount of time "python" occurs rather, the count.

Is there a way a neat way to get the count instead of creating an empty list and appending to it to get the count.

I have tried

```
count = []

for i in response:
    count.append(i)

print(len(count))
```

Sure there is a better way to get the count of occurrence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `es`? *PS: The for loop and that list is useless, simply `len(response)`...*

Comment: Es is elasticsearch host.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz for making me feel stupid. Genuinely thank you.